# Coleman mini bike ct200u

Tags: throttle, mini-bike, coleman

My bike just takes off on its own. When I turn the choker on. Not sure what it wrong with it. It’s just take off on it’s own

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A choke control can raise the idling revs. So the engine isn't exactly idling.

Comment: You may just need to adjust the amount of throttle added by the choke mechanism.

Comment: If choke is adjustable, either readjust it right after starting up a cold engine so the minibike doesn't take off while the engine warms up or turn off choke. Choke startup helps put more gas into cold engines and usually removed once the engine runs. The trick is use the least amount of choke after cold engine startup. Using full choke with the minibike taking off will wear out the automatic clutch shoes.